# C++ Compiler not found with Code::Blocks

Tags: c++, c

I am new to programming `C` but not new to programming. I have downloaded Code::Blocks to build `C` projects with but when I start a new project it says it can't find a compiler. I downloaded GNU GCC Compiler and when I create a new Project it still says it can't find the compiler. The compiler is downloaded on my `C:` drive so I'm guessing I have to link the two together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you downloaded IDE with compiler. If not do so. It's large size version comes with compiler. It comes with MinGW GCC compiler.
OR
go to settings in the upper part -> click compiler -> choose reset to defaults.

This link might help.
http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Installing_a_supported_compiler

Comment: Resetting the compiler worked. Thank you very much for your help!